# Run-time error '6': overflow for VBA scripting

Tags: excel, vba, error-handling, runtime-error, overflow

I tried to implement this code in VBA but it keeps bumping the error of "Overflow"
Could someone help to check what's wrong with my code?
Thanks.

I tried to debug a few times for the Distance Matrix in the code, but it did not work.

Not sure what problem occurred here, maybe some silly typo or the solution was wrong?

I am trying to find the minimum costs of establishing 5 facilities for 55 cities.

```
Function CalculateDistance(lat1 As Double, lon1 As Double, lat2 As Double, lon2 As Double) As       Variant

 Dim R As Double
 R = 6371 ' Radius of the Earth in kilometers

Dim dlat As Double
dlat = WorksheetFunction.Radians(lat2 - lat1)

Dim dlon As Double
dlon = WorksheetFunction.Radians(lon2 - lon1)

Dim a As Double
a = Sin(dlat / 2) * Sin(dlat / 2) + Cos(WorksheetFunction.Radians(lat1)) * Cos(WorksheetFunction.Radians(lat2)) * Sin(dlon / 2) * Sin(dlon / 2)

Dim c As Double
c = 2 * WorksheetFunction.Atan2(Sqr(1 - a), Sqr(a))

If R * c <= 1E+308 Then        

CalculateDistance = R * c ' Output in Km

Else

    CalculateDistance = "Distance exceeds maximum limit"

End If

Debug.Print "HaversineDistance: " & CalculateDistance

End Function

Sub CalculatePrintDistanceMatrix()
' Calculate the distance matrix for all pairs of cities

Dim WSData As Worksheet
'Initiatate worksheets
Set WSData = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data")

Dim sh As Worksheet
Dim sheetExists As Boolean
'Check if "DistanceMatrix" sheet exists
sheetExists = False
For Each sh In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
   If sh.Name = "DistanceMatrix" Then
      sheetExists = True
      Exit For
    End If
Next sh

Dim WSOutput As Worksheet
' If "DistanceMatrix" exists, clear it; otherwise, add a new sheet
If sheetExists Then
    Set WSOutput = sh
    WSOutput.Cells.Clear
Else
    Set WSOutput =    ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add(After:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count))
    WSOutput.Name = "DistanceMatrix"
End If

Dim nCities As Long
' Count number of cities (rows) in the Data sheet
nCities = WSData.Cells(WSData.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row - 1 ' Assumes headers in row 1

 ' Initialize the distances array

 Dim Distances() As Variant
 ReDim Distances(1 To nCities, 1 To nCities)

 Dim i As Long, j As Long
 Dim lat1 As Double, lon1 As Double, lat2 As Double, lon2 As Double
 ' Calculate distances
 'Read Data from the sheet "Data"
 For i = 2 To nCities + 1
 For j = 2 To nCities + 1
   lat1 = WSData.Cells(i, 2).Value
   lon1 = WSData.Cells(i, 3).Value
   lat2 = WSData.Cells(j, 2).Value
   lon2 = WSData.Cells(j, 3).Value

        Distances(i - 1, j - 1) = CalculateDistance(lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2)
    Next j
Next i

'Print the distance matrix to the new sheet

For i = 1 To nCities
  For j = 1 To nCities
    WSOutput.Cells(i + 1, j + 1).Value = Distances(i, j)
Next j
Next i

'Print city names as headers
For i = 2 To nCities + 1
   WSOutput.Cells(1, i).Value = WSData.Cells(i, 1).Value ' Column headers
   WSOutput.Cells(i, 1).Value = WSData.Cells(i, 1).Value ' Row headers
Next i

End Sub

Function CalculateFacilityCost(cityIndex As Long, FacilityLocations() As Boolean) As Double
Dim nCities As Long
nCities = UBound(FacilityLocations)

Dim cost As Double
cost = 0

Dim i As Long
Dim j As Long

Dim Distances() As Variant
Dim HousePrices() As Double

ReDim HousePrices(1 To nCities)
ReDim Distances(1 To nCities, 1 To nCities) ' Resize the Distances array

Dim WSData As Worksheet
Set WSData = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data")

For i = 2 To nCities + 1
    HousePrices(i - 1) = WSData.Cells(i, 5).Value
Next i

' Calculate and populate the Distances array
   For i = 1 To nCities
    For j = 1 To nCities
        Distances(i, j) = CalculateDistance(WSData.Cells(i + 1, 2).Value, WSData.Cells(i + 1,  3).Value, WSData.Cells(j + 1, 2).Value, WSData.Cells(j + 1, 3).Value)
    Next j
Next i

For i = 1 To nCities
    If FacilityLocations(i) Then
        cost = cost + Distances(cityIndex, i) * HousePrices(i)
    End If
Next i

CalculateFacilityCost = cost ' Return the calculated cost

End Function

Sub GreedyHeuristics()
Dim WSData As Worksheet
Set WSData = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data")

Dim nCities As Long
nCities = WSData.Cells(WSData.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row - 1

Dim nFacilities As Long
nFacilities = 5 ' Set the number of facilities to establish

Dim FacilityLocations() As Boolean
ReDim FacilityLocations(1 To nCities) ' Boolean array to track facility locations

Dim Distances() As Variant
ReDim Distances(1 To nCities, 1 To nCities)

Dim i As Long
Dim j As Long
Dim minCost As Double
Dim minIndex As Long

' Step 1: Find the city with the highest population

'Read data

 Dim Population() As Double
 Dim HousePrices() As Double
 ReDim Population(1 To nCities)
 ReDim HousePrices(1 To nCities)

For i = 2 To nCities + 1
    Population(i - 1) = WSData.Cells(i, 4).Value
    HousePrices(i - 1) = WSData.Cells(i, 5).Value
Next i

Dim maxPopulation As Double
Dim maxIndex As Long
maxPopulation = WorksheetFunction.Max(Population)
maxIndex = WorksheetFunction.Match(maxPopulation, Population, 0)
FacilityLocations(maxIndex) = True

For i = 2 To nFacilities
    ' Step 2: Calculate the cost of establishing a facility in each city
    For j = 1 To nCities
        If Not FacilityLocations(j) Then ' Only consider cities without facilities
            Dim totalCost As Double
            totalCost = CalculateFacilityCost(j, FacilityLocations)

            ' Step 3: Find the city with the minimum cost
            If j = 1 Or totalCost < minCost Then
                minCost = totalCost
                minIndex = j
            End If
        End If
    Next j

    ' Step 4: Select the city with the minimum cost as the next facility location
    FacilityLocations(minIndex) = True
Next i

' Step 5: Print the selected facility locations
For i = 1 To nCities
    If FacilityLocations(i) Then
        Debug.Print "Facility located at City " & i
    End If
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Welcom to SO. Overflow error means you are trying to save a value in a data type which limit range is lower than your value. Check [Data type summary](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/data-type-summary). Also, please,**specify which line throws the error**.